# Programmatically convert Doc(x) files to PDF using Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, pdf, java, docx

We are developing a Java application that needs to programmatically convert .rtf, .doc and .docx files to PDF files.

Formatting is important to us, so we need the page numbers to be the same between a source file and a target PDF file, and the contents of each page being the same as the original file.

We have tried out open source solutions, such as [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) to invoke a LibreOffice of OpenOffice installation, [Docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) and [XDocReport](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/). The best formatting was achieved with LibreOffice. However, even in that case, the pages were different (for example, a 87-page .rtf file results in an 80-page PDF file).

So, we think that the ideal way to make the conversion would be to somehow invoke Microsoft Word though our Java application, and make the conversion with it. That would produce PDF files that have the same formatting as the original files.

Is this possible in any of the following ways:

- An API that is directly invokeable through Java?
- An API that is invokeable through a .Net language and we would use that with something like [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)?
- A 3rd party library that uses a Microsoft Word installation under the hood (something like JODConverter for Word)?
- A CLI interface supported by Word (relevant [question](https://superuser.com/questions/393118/how-to-convert-word-doc-to-pdf-from-windows-command-line))?
- Something else?

Comment: I haven't because it is suggested by Microsoft not to use Word this way.